# XQuery -- Searching for full tags based on parts of a tag

Tags: xquery

I am having some issues when tackling a task in XQuery, FLWOR to be precise.
In one file, I deal with tags of full names, such as

```
<name>Neil Guyman</name> 

but another xml file deals with

<firstname>Neil</firstname>

<secondname>Guyman</secondname>
```

Anyways, would this require any act of parsing?

Comment: Would *what* require any act of parsing?

Comment: That's true...I never asked the question! I want to be able to find the last name of the file based on the the last name in just "name". I need to extract just the last part!

Comment: @NeilGuyman What file? Can you give an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there would be a parent element to these name elements that you can iterate over. If not, it's less pretty but you could just iterate over the first two and join the two elements for that case:

```
for $n in //(name | firstname)
return
  typeswitch($n)
    case element(name) return $n/string()
    case element(firstname) return string-join(($n, $n/following-sibling::secondname),' ')
    default **maybe throw an error?**
```